# How to change or reference Nuget Package Version on props file

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, nuget

I am building a Nuget Package that will only contain a pre built CLI Tool and as part of this package I need to move such tool to the bin folder of the project that referenced it. I am accomplishing by adding a `props` file to my package:

```
<Project>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="$(NuGetPackageRoot)/packageid/1.0.0.3/tools/*" Link="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" ExcludeFromSingleFile="true" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

As you can see, I have hardcoded the package version in the path, which I really don't want to do.

I am planning on building the package using `nuget pack PackageId -version 1.0.0.3`.

So, is there an MSBUild variable that will use the package version or a way to replace it while using `nuget pack`?

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished the same thing by replacing the version number using the `sed` command before packaging it. I added it as a step in my Azure Dev OPS pipeline